# Is it possible to have a sort of scroll view in expanded notification?

Tags: android, view, notifications, scrollview

I have added buttons to my expanded notification, there are quite a few.
The idea is to do a power control in the notification or display recent Apps there.
However, `LayoutInflater` doesn't allow `ScrollView` to be inflated for `RemoteViewsv.

There must be a workaround for this: to allow UI in the expanded notification scrollable left and right. Like how HTC Sense does  it with recent Apps.

```
06-18 15:10:24.991: ERROR/StatusBar(1251): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.ScrollView
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Like how HTC Sense does it with recent apps.

HTC Sense, being part of the firmware implementation, is not using `RemoteViews`.

The rest of your analysis is correct -- you cannot put a `ScrollView` in a `RemoteViews`.